# what does this rails code do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

What will this code do?

What is the purpose of using collect in this code?

If collect method is not used what will happen??

```
<%= select_tag(isTemplate ? '__template__time_entry[][project_id]' : 'time_entry[][project_id]', 
               options_for_select(@projects.collect{|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, 
                                 :selected =>  entry.nil? ? 0 : entry.project_id), 
               :onchange => 'projectChanged(this,' + @row.to_s() + ')', 
               :style=> 'width:150px' ) %>
```

When i execute this, the error "undefined method collect" is displayed.
I'm using redmine0.8.2 and rails2.0.2 on linux. This is a bit of code from one of my plugins.

Answer (score 3):

This code display a select input with options.

Your error is probably due to `@projects` is nil and undefined. You try to collect which is a method for Array or Hash whereas your variable is nil.

You must define it in you controller with an array or a hash, but probably with an Array containing Project objects.